# New to C, Return pointer to 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return-type

I've been trying to convert a program from Java to C, it's a emulator of a watch and to display the time I'm using Ascii art. I have stored all the numbers (0-9) in 2D char arrays (fx. 9):

```
char nine[7][5] = {
    { '0', '0', '0', '0' },
    { '0', ' ', ' ', '0' },
    { '0', ' ', ' ', '0' },
    { '0', '0', '0', '0' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' }
};
```

I now have a function which job is to convert the time stored in a int array (fx. 22:04:59, would be stored as 220459 in the array). The function should return the corresponding Ascii art to each digit, so that I finally can call the function that prints the time (in ascii form) that takes 6 char[][] parameters.

So in short, I need to know which 6 parameters to call this function with:

```
void printScreen(char hourFirstDigit[7][5], char hourSecondDigit[7][5], char minuteFirstDigit[7][5], char minuteSecondDigit[7][5], char secFirstDigit[7][5], char secSecondDigit[7][5])
```

In java my solution was simply to make a function that returned a char[][] array, and then a switch statement for the 10 cases (0-9), (here's the first few lines):

```
char timeToAsciiArt[][](int digitNumber, int small) {
switch (timeRightNow[digitNumber]) {
    case 0:
    return zero;
}
```

Possible solution:
I've read that there where at least two possible solutions to the problem (in general), 1. Replace by a pointer to an array. 2. Wrap with a struct.

My thoughts on:
1. I'm really not sure how I would return to a pointer to an array (could someone explain how to do this with case 0: as an example? :)

Comment: `char (*timeToAsciiArt(int, int))[7][5] {switch(/**/){case 0: return &zero;}}`. Alternatively: `char (*timeToAsciiArt(int, int)[5] {switch(/**/){case 0: return zero;}}`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I ended up using your solution :) .

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting  the following.approach.

Define a function that will contain an array of the images with static storage duration.

For example

```
char ( * )[7][5] get_image( size_t i )
{
    static char images[10][7][5] = 
    {
        //...
        {
            { '0', '0', '0', '0' },
            { '0', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { '0', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { '0', '0', '0', '0' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' }
        }
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( images ) / sizeof( *images );

    return i < N ? images[i] : NULL;
}
```

Or maybe it will be better if the function has return type `char ( * )[5]`

For example

```
char ( * )[5] get_image( size_t i )
{
    static char images[10][7][5] = 
    {
        //...
        {
            { '0', '0', '0', '0' },
            { '0', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { '0', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { '0', '0', '0', '0' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ', '0' }
        }
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( images ) / sizeof( *images );

    return i < N ? images[i][0] : NULL;
}
```

Then write a function that will return in a structure an array of 6 elements with corresponding digits. These elements will serve as arguments to call function `get_image`.

That is enough.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you wish to have :

- Some kind of storage for your ASCII art ;
- A function which receives a digit and return some pointer to the corresponding ASCII art storage ;
- A function which receives a set of ASCII arts and prints them.

---

## Storing the ASCII art

It could be wise to wrap your ASCII art into a structure, since you could then store more data about it. Perhaps in the future you will want to have a thinner `1` digit ; you would need to store data about the size of each ASCII art :

```
struct ascii_digit {
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    char[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH] art; //Here you could instead use a pointer
                                     //instead of storing directly
}
```

Of course if you absolutely don't plan on having something other than a fixed size, arrays are fine.

---

## Finding the correct ASCII art

When passing arrays around in C, you usually do not pass the array directly : you usually use a pointer to it. So a correct prototype for your function would not be

```
char time_to_ascii_art[][](int digit_number, int small);
```

but rather, if you use structures

```
struct ascii_digit* time_to_ascii_art(int digit_number, int small);
```

> Note that we return a pointer to a structure. While it is absolutely possible to directly pass a structure, it may not be considered good practice as it induces some overhead depending on the size of your structure.

or you can use a naïve approach using pointers to `char` :

```
char* time_to_ascii_art(int digit_number, int small);
```

Note that if you have a `char*` pointer to a bidimensional array, you will have to do the math by yourself when trying to access its contents. For example, accessing the `y`th member of the `x`th row : `array[width * x + y]`. To spare yourself from doing this, you can use pointers to arrays :

```
char (*time_to_ascii_art)(int digit_number, int small)[ASCII_ART_WIDTH];
```

In this function you could either use a `switch … case` statement like you did in Java ( example using structures ) :

```
// Let's say that your structures are declared in the global scope as ascii_zero, ascii_one…
struct ascii_digit* time_to_ascii_art(int digit_number, int small)
{
    switch(digit_number) {
        case 0:
          return ascii_zero;
        case 1:
          return ascii_one;
        default:
          return NULL;
    }
}
```

or you could — which would also probably be a good idea in Java — have an array containing your ASCII arts, or pointer to them, indexed so that accessing the `n`th member will give you the ASCII art for the digit `n` :

```
// Let's now say you have an ascii_digits array of structs containing your digits
struct ascii_digit* time_to_ascii_art(int digit_number, int small)
{
    return ascii_digits + digit_number; // You should handle bad values.
    // ascii_digits being an array, it is implicitly cast to a pointer here.
}
```

---

## Passing the ASCII arts to the display function

Now to pass your ASCII arts to your display function you can — depending on the datatype you chose — use either pointers to structures :

```
void print_screen(struct ascii_digit* hour_first_digit, …);
```

pointers to `char` :

```
void print_screen(char* hour_first_digit, …);
```

or pointers to array of chars :

```
void print_screen(char (*hour_first_digit)[ASCII_ART_WIDTH], …);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C an array *is* a pointer. When you pass a parameter it is always by copy, so when you "send" an array you send a copy of a pointer, not a copy of the array.

Structs are copied by value (as `int`, `float`…), and can have inside a static array:

```
typedef struct {
  char tab[7][5];
}Digit;
```

So you can create variables: `Digit zero, one, two…` and set values into it: `zero.tab[0][0] = ' ';`. And you can pass it to functions or return it, it will be copied.

Now for dealing with pointers (better in my opinion as you don't *need* to duplicate these arrays): an array is still a pointer. But "static" 2D arrays are a bit *strange* (it is not an array of arrays). As mentionned in comment by EOF your arrays are in fact (*)[5]. So it lead to something a little bit complicated to match all the types:

```
char (*select_digit(int val))[5] {
  if (value == 0) return zero;
  if (value == 1) return one;
  …
}
```

Your `printScreen` function is the same.
To store a pointer returned by this `select_digit` function you have to declare it like this:

```
char (*tmp)[5];
tmp = select_digit(5);
printScreen(tmp, …);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using arrays and pointers would more or less translate to :

```
char (* timeToAsciiArt(unsigned timeNow[6], unsigned digitNumber) )[5] {
    static char asc0[7][5] = { //fill in };
    static char asc1[7][5] = { //fill in };
    switch (timeNow[digitNumber]) {
    case 0:
        return asc0;
    case 1:
        return asc1;
    ...
 }
```

You can then pass the returned art to `print_screen` by

```
unsigned timeNow[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
char (*first_digit)[5] = timeToAsciiArt(timeNow, 0);
printScreen(first_digit, ... , );
```

or directly

```
printScreen( timeToAsciiArt(timeNow, 0) , ...);
```

In the end, this serves to say that wrapping in a `struct` will gain you a much more readable code.